# recursive compare directoreis content by cmd windows xp to output file

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, cmd.exe

I wish to compare two directories and subdirectories files recursively,
without additional instalation in windows xp.
the tree of the folders and files name is same, but files's contents  may be different.
Is any way to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: yes there is a way to do it, but have you tried something by yourself already ? Some clues : `for`, `dir /s`, `comp`

Comment: Yes, I have tried every option I found but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank G-D , I found it:
 Comparative folders- dir1 and dir2 are on drive D.
The file logfile.txt for comparable results is also in drive D.
in the batch file:

```
  D:
setlocal enableextensions 
setlocal ENABLEDELAYED EXPANSION 
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set filename=logfile.txt
echo. 2>%filename%
cd dir1
(for /r %%i in (*) do set p=%%i&if exist "D:\dir2\!p:~8!" (FC "%%i" "D:\dir2\!p:~8!" | FIND "FC: no dif" > nul&IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (echo !!! file %%i is different >> d:\%filename%)) else (echo !!! file"D:\dir2\!p:~8!" not found >> d:\%filename%))>nul
cd ..\dir2
(for /r %%i in (*) do set p=%%i&if not exist "D:\dir1\!p:~8!"   (echo !!! file "D:\dir1\!p:~8!"  not found >> d:\%filename%))>nul
cd ..
start %filename%
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick, assuming, as you said, that source and target tree are the same :

```
@ECHO OFF
set myrootfolder1=c:\stack\rootfolder1
set myrootfolder2=c:\stack\rootfolder2
set logfile=c:\stack\compare.log

type NUL > %logfile%

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /R %myrootfolder1% %%G IN (*.*) DO (
    set sourcefile=%%G
    set targetfile=!sourcefile:%myrootfolder1%=%myrootfolder2%!
    echo N | comp /A !sourcefile! !targetfile! | find "OK" > nul
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 echo !sourcefile! and !targetfile! are different >>%logfile%
)
```

This will render a logfile like this :

> c:\stack\rootfolder1\file1.txt and c:\stack\rootfolder2\file1.txt are
>   different 
>       c:\stack\rootfolder1\sub1\file2.txt and c:\stack\rootfolder2\sub1\file2.txt are different

Edit : i did not use `fc` here because bugs have been reported for Windows XP when the command compares files that differ every 128th byte of a character string.
My reference : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953929/en-us

But follow @Synetech comments for more info ;) thanks to him !

Comment: Even something simpler like the following should work (of course, make sure to adjust the paths): `for /r %i in (c:\a\*) do (fc /b %i c:\b%~dpi > nul && if errorlevel 1 if not errorlevel 2 echo %i -- %~dpi >> c:\filediffs.log)`

Comment: `bugs have been reported for Windows XP when difference is upper than 128 bits` Huh? What does that mean? I have never encountered a problem with it–yet. What bugs?

Comment: @Synetech : here : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953929/en-us but it should work with no pb i guess ;)

Comment: [Or this.](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2524020) That only affects text-mode comparisons. I *never* use text comparisons (not even back in the DOS days), I *always* use binary comparison with the `/b` switch. Not only is it necessary for binary files, but it is safer with text-files, so it is just better to always do binary comparisons when dealing with mixed or unknown files like in this case. (If I want to do text comparisons, I just open them both in a text-editor.) `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this batch in pure DOS. It can compare two folders with subfolders and displays visual messages during the comparison. It is useful for small trees of folders, so you can immediately see the errors in the console screen while the comparison is performed.

Note: The comparison will pause if a comparison error occur !
It does not produce an error log, however it is possible to redirect the error Echo to a log file and cut the Pause command.

For large folder's trees or content is better to use specific tools like ROBOCOPY or similar that produce very detailed Reports, both for copy and comparison.

```
@Echo OFF
echo.
echo  Compares Files in two or more Folders or Paths
echo ================================================
echo.

set /P Src= Digit or Paste HERE Path n.1 : 
::set Src=YourPath
echo.
set /P Dst= Digit or Paste HERE Path n.2 : 
::set Dst=YourPath
echo.
PAUSE
echo.

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /R "%Src%" %%A IN (*.*) DO (
  set SFold="%%A"
  set TFold=!SFold:%Src%=%Dst%!
  set P1="%%~dpA"

  if "!P2!" EQU "" set P2=!P1!
  if "!P1!" NEQ "!P2!" echo ----------------------------------------------------- Compare Folder is Changed & echo.
  FC !SFold! !TFold!
  if !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 echo. - ERROR - ==================================================================== & PAUSE
  set P2=!P1!
)
echo.
echo ====================================
echo      COMPARE TERMINATED . . . .
echo ====================================
echo.
PAUSE
```